# iOS6 UIStoryboard how to add a UICollectionReusableView to a UICollectionView object?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios6, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

I'm running into a silly issue when working with a `UICollectionView` - I've added a "`UICollectionReusableView`" by dragging it to within the `UICollectionView` at the top position. I'm expecting that this is a kind of a header that would be visible (similar to `UITableView`). However, when I run the app, **I see a blank space** of height equal to that of the reusable view over the cells, but nothing else is showing.

**What other steps do I need to take to make sure that my reusable view, defined in storyboard shows up when the app is running?**

Answer (score 1):

You need to subclass UICollectionResusableView and implement -(UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{